# Unable to access and download Sentinel-2 images from Python API with the standard code

Tags: python, error, api, sentinel-2, download

```
products = api.query(footprint.wkt,
                     date = ('20161101', '20161116'),
                     platformname = 'Sentinel-2',
                     processinglevel = 'Level-2A',
                     cloudcoverpercentage = (0,10)
                    )
print (len(products))
```

Another Error while accessing sentinel data from APi python for the above same code is:

```
KeyError    Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sentinelsat/sentinel.py
in _load_subquery(self, query, order_by, limit, offset)

    394     json_feed = response.json()["feed"]
--> 395     if json_feed["opensearch:totalResults"] is None:
    396
```

We are using some unintended behavior of the server that a null is KeyError: 'opensearch:totalResults'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
SentinelAPIError  Traceback (most recent call last)
3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sentinelsat/sentinel.py in _load_subquery(self, query, order_by, limit, offset)

    401           total_results = int(json_feed["opensearch:totalResults"])
    402       except (ValueError, KeyError):
--> 403           raise SentinelAPIError("API response not valid. JSON decoding failed.", response)
    404 
    405       products = json_feed.get("entry", [])


SentinelAPIError: HTTP status 200 OK: API response not valid. JSON decoding failed.
```

Comment: It seems like your footprint is formed by too much coordinate pairs, can you share its display?

Comment: @ Deniz Yes sure.. I have included it in the question above. This footprint is from a shapefile.. will it be advisable to convert this shapefile into a GeoJSON format and create the footprint? I have a doubt that this would be helpful because number of coordinate pairs will remain same.

Comment: You should shorten the query string. To achieve you can simplify the polygon or generate a bounding box to query Sentinel2 API. I am using Geopandas for such data manipulation, its envelope, convex_hull props or or simplify function will work in your case..

Comment: Thanks @Deniz. I will try that.

Comment: This worked easily with envelope but again I am getting another error while downloading. i.e. SentinelAPIError: HTTP status 200 OK: API response not valid. JSON decoding failed. –

Comment: I've the same problem. I'm using a bounding box